# actionscrip3 textfield sizeing end centering

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to get some words from xml and put them an the stage side by side in the center of the stage. I achieved this by the code below. I auto resize textfield according to  text inside.  But this time there comes space between words.  What  I accomplish is to have  autoresized and adjacent words without space between them. But I could not solve the problem.
Could you please help me to solve it. 
Thanks in advance

```
                var partsWidth=100;              
                var wordTf = new TextField();
                wordTf.name =thispart;
                wordTf.text =thispart;
                wordTf.width=partsWidth;
                xStartPoint=stage.stageWidth / 2  -  (numberOfWords * partsWidth )/2;
                wordTf.height=partsHeight;
                wordTf.x= xStartPoint + (index * partsWidth) ;
                wordTf.y=150;
                wordTf.background=true;
                wordTf.backgroundColor = 0xe3e3e3;

                wordTf.border = true;
                var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
                    myFormat.size = 16;
                    myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;

                wordTf.setTextFormat(myFormat);
                wordTf.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                addChild(wordTf);
```

Comment: between words. since the partsWidth value is 100 (or set something else) there comes the space between words. but if I remove width value, I can not calculate locations and centering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting the width explicit with `wordTf.width=partsWidth;`. this will override the autosize option. I would use the following code.

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();

var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myFormat.size = 16;
    myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;

for each( var thispart:String in parts ) 
{
    var wordTf = new TextField();
    wordTf.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    wordTf.name = thispart;
    wordTf.text = thispart;
    wordTf.height=partsHeight;
    wordTf.background=true;
    wordTf.backgroundColor = 0xe3e3e3;
    wordTf.border = true;
    wordTf.width = wordTf.textWidth + 4;
    wordTf.y=150;
    wordTf.x = container.width;
    container.addChild(wordTf);
}

container.x = (stage.stageWidth - container.width) / 2;
addChild(container);
```

add your words to a separate sprite, and after all words added, add this sprite to the stage and center it.

The line

```
wordTf.width = wordTf.textWidth + 4;
```

is the important one. After setting the text, flash can calculate the width of the text. now set this text width (+4 is a fixed padding around the text in a text field you can't modify) as width of your textfield.

Comment: Had some mistakes in the code. this should finally work. No need to have widths to calculate.

Comment: that is ok.. but xStartpoint is still calculated by partsWidth so there is still spaces between words. What I am after is to have differently sized textfields side by side(touch each other) and centered on stage.

Comment: @mustafa: this is exactly what is done in my code. I don't know if you are going thru a loop or so, I'll modify my code with a loop in a minute.

Comment: I got rid of xStartPoint here and use container.width. (important to do that before adding the new text field). You could also use `wordTf.getBounds(container).right` after adding it to set a new xStartPoint.

Comment: @DanelB : I got some errors from the codeScene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 61 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before var.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 61 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon.

Comment: Sorry I had a spelling use "for each" instead of "foreach". But I can't debug your entire flash and do not know what is in line 61. Syntax errors you can easily fix yourself. I mainly posted an approach for your problem.